# Nothing seen on serial monitor - MPU6050 with pic16f886

Tags: pic, i2c, uart, accelerometer, gyroscope

I'm trying to interface mpu6050 module with pic16f886 microcontroller. But, nothing's getting displayed on serial monitor. Been stuck here since many days. USART code works fine. I've tried that separately. Now, i'm not sure if there's a problem with my i2c code or mpu code. Kindly help.

**i2c.c code**

```
#include <xc.h>
#include "i2cheader_master.h"
#define _XTAL_FREQ 4000000
#define I2C_SPEED 100000


void i2c_init(void){
    TRISC3=1;
    TRISC4=1;

    SSPADD= ((_XTAL_FREQ/4)/I2C_SPEED)-1;
    SSPSTAT=0x80;
    SSPCON=0x28;
    SSPCON2=0x00;
}

void i2c_start_write(char slave_add){
    while(1){
    SSPCON2bits.SEN = 1;            /* Send START condition */
    while(SSPCON2bits.SEN);         /* Wait for completion of START */
    SSPIF = 0;
    if(!SSPSTATbits.S)              /* Continue if START is failed */
        continue;
    i2c_write(slave_add);           /* Write slave device address with write to communicate */
    if(ACKSTAT)                     /* Check whether Acknowledgment received or not */
    {
        i2c_stop();                 /* If not then initiate STOP and continue */
        continue;
    }    
    break;                          /* If yes then break loop */
    }
}

int i2c_restart_write(char slave_add){
    RSEN = 1;                                                                   /* Send REPEATED START condition */
    while(SSPCON2bits.RSEN);                                                    /* Wait for completion of REPEATED START condition */
    SSPIF = 0;
    if(!SSPSTATbits.S)                                                          /* Return 0 if REPEATED START is failed */
    return 0;
    i2c_write(slave_add);                                                       /* Write slave device address with read to communicate */
    if (ACKSTAT)                    /* Return 2 if acknowledgment received else 1 */
     return 1;
    else
     return 2;
}

void i2c_stop(void){
    SSPCON2bits.PEN=1;
    while(!SSPIF);
    SSPIF=0;
}

void i2c_ack(){
    ACKDT=0;
    ACKEN=1;
    while(ACKEN);
}

void i2c_nack(){
    ACKDT=1;
    ACKEN=1;
    while(ACKEN);
}

int i2c_write(unsigned char data){
    SSPBUF=data;
    while(!SSPIF);
    SSPIF=0;
    return ACKSTAT;
}

unsigned char i2c_read(unsigned ack){
    SSPCON2bits.RCEN=1;
    while(!SSPIF);
    SSPIF=0;
    if (ack)
        i2c_ack();
    else
        i2c_nack();
    return SSPBUF;
}
```

**mpu.c code**

```
#include <xc.h>
#include "header_mpu.h"
#include "i2cheader_master.h"
#include "header_uart.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define _XTAL_FREQ 4000000
#define baud 9600


void mpu_init(){
    __delay_ms(150);

    i2c_start_write(0xD0);                                                      //slave write address
    i2c_write(SMPLRT_DIV);                                                      //write to sample rate register(write to this address)
    i2c_write(0x07);                                                            //1KHZ sample rate(write to data)
    i2c_stop();

    i2c_start_write(0xD0);                                                      //slave write address
    i2c_write(PWR_MGMT_1);
    i2c_write(0x01);                                                            //x-axis gyro reference frequency
    i2c_stop();

    i2c_start_write(0xD0);                                                      //slave write address
    i2c_write(CONFIG);
    i2c_write(0x01);                                                            //fs=1KHZ
    i2c_stop();

    i2c_start_write(0xD0);                                                      //slave write address
    i2c_write(GYRO_CONFIG);
    i2c_write(0x18);                                                            //full scale range +/- 2000 deg/c
    i2c_stop();

    i2c_start_write(0xD0);                                                      //slave write address
    i2c_write(INT_ENABLE);
    i2c_write(0x01);
    i2c_stop();
}

void mpu_start(){
    i2c_start_write(0xD0);                                                      //slave write address
    i2c_write(ACCEL_XOUT_H);                                                    //start from where to read
    i2c_restart_write(0xD1);                                                    /* I2C start with device read address */

}

void usart_init(){
    TRISC6=0;
    TRISC7=1;
//    SPBRG=_XTAL_FREQ/(16*baud) -1;
    SPBRG=25;                                                                   //pg.no - 163
    TXSTAbits.BRGH=1;
    TXSTAbits.SYNC=0;
    RCSTAbits.SPEN=1;
    TXSTAbits.TXEN=1;
    RCSTAbits.CREN=1;
    TXSTAbits.TX9=0;
    RCSTAbits.RX9=0;
    RCSTAbits.FERR = 0;     // Disable framing error
    RCSTAbits.OERR = 0;     // Disable overrun error
}

void usart_send_byte(char bt){
    while(TXIF==0);
    TXREG=bt;
}


void usart_send_string(char* str) {
    while(*str!= '\0')
        usart_send_byte(*str++);
}

void main(){
    char buffer[20];
    int ax,ay,az,gx,gy,gz,T;
    float xa,ya,za,xg,yg,zg,t;
    OSCCON=0x72;
    i2c_init();
    usart_init();
    mpu_init();

    while(1){
        mpu_start();
        ax=(((int)i2c_read(0)<<8)|(int)i2c_read(0));
        ay=(((int)i2c_read(0)<<8)|(int)i2c_read(0));
        az=(((int)i2c_read(0)<<8)|(int)i2c_read(0));
        T=(((int)i2c_read(0)<<8)|(int)i2c_read(0));
        gx=(((int)i2c_read(0)<<8)|(int)i2c_read(0));
        gy=(((int)i2c_read(0)<<8)|(int)i2c_read(0));
        gz=(((int)i2c_read(0)<<8)|(int)i2c_read(1));                            //no ack . hence, stop read

        i2c_stop();

        xa =(float)ax/16384.0;
        ya =(float)ay/16384.0;
        za =(float)az/16384.0;
        t=((float)T/340.00)+36.53;
        xg=(float)gx/131.0;
        yg=(float)gx/131.0;
        zg=(float)gx/131.0;        

        sprintf(buffer,"ax=%.2f g\t",xa);                                       //Take values in buffer and send it over to Usart
        usart_send_string(buffer);

        sprintf(buffer,"ay=%.2f g\t",ya);                                       
        usart_send_string(buffer);

        sprintf(buffer,"az=%.2f g\t",za);                                       
        usart_send_string(buffer);

        sprintf(buffer,"T = %.2f%cC\t",t,0xF8);                                 /* 0xF8 Ascii value of degree '°' on serial */                                       
        usart_send_string(buffer);

        sprintf(buffer," Gx = %.2f%c/s\t",xg,0xF8);                                       
        usart_send_string(buffer);

        sprintf(buffer," Gy = %.2f%c/s\t",yg,0xF8);                                       
        usart_send_string(buffer);

        sprintf(buffer," Gz = %.2f%c/s\t",zg,0xF8);                                       
        usart_send_string(buffer);
        __delay_ms(500);
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Have you considered adding additional UART writes at various stages of your I2C code to see where it's getting stuck?

Comment: @brhans: The RX LED on my USB - TTL serial module and on my serial monitor (I'm using coolterm and putty) isn't blinking. So, i figured that no transmission is going on. But what you said makes sense, I'll give it a go. Thanks!

Comment: If you have additional information related to your original question, use the "edit" button to add the information there. Do not create a duplicate question.